# How to override checkout cart page in custom theme magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout-page, custom-theme

> I am trying to override checkout page some text using custom theme
>   magento 2??

Comment: You can add Magento_Checkout folder to your custom theme. Add required layout/templates file under this folder to add changes/updates in your theme files. You can copy them from module-checkout resides at vendor/magento/module-checkout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create below path in your custom theme:

```
app/design/frontend/{{your package}}/{{your theme}}/Magento_Checkout/
```

Copy the required template, layout or web files to be modified from

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend
```

Update the files and flush cache to get the changes reflected. If you are modifying web files then don't forget to redeploy the content by running below commands:

**php bin/magento s:up;
php bin/magento s:s:d;
php bin/magento c:f**

Comment: thanks yes i have idea  but i am not able to find out checkout page text headings in templates files do you have any idea

Comment: Could you please let me know the exact heading text to be updated, I'll find it for you and give you the path..

Comment: Delivery address,Order Summary

Comment: order summary could be updated in vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/Summary.html I hope you have idea to copy this file under your theme, let me know if any help needed.

Comment: Copy file vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary.html and put it in your custom theme at app/design/frontend/{{your package}}/{{your theme}}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary.html, update the title and deploy the content to update title..  For Delivery address I can't find this text in default checkout module. Let me check and provide you more details on it if possible..

Comment: I think you are looking for "Shipping Address" title to update, if yes then it could be managed via shipping.html available at same location vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html, override it in your custom theme.